# Phonegap and Blackberry OS5.0

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've been working with phonegap for the last 3 months, and have used it
to port my apps to Android, iPhone and Blackberry 6.0 and they run ok.

However, with Blackberry v5.0, the onDeviceReady event doesn't fire.  It is like the phonegap library was not loaded. The same app runs perfectly on Blackberry v6, and the problem is present on both the device and the emulator.

Searching in other posts and forums, it seems to be caused by some errors in javascript code, that the Blackberry 5.0 browser detects as error, and after this the phonegap library doesn't load.

Does this make sense? how can I verify this? nothing shows in the console
What else might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this so this is just a wild guess, but I think the Blackberry OS 5.0 came with a browser that did not support proper event propagation.

Maybe (just maybe) you just don`t see the device ready event, although the device is actually ready. Maybe just to try start your app with setTimeout set to a hight value just to verify.